# Raspberry Pi with camera module as webcam?

Tags: camera, webcam, streaming

I have been running the raspberry Pi with camera module for a little time right now as my "outdoor camera" (because I couldn't really afford a nice camera for on the road).
now that I have a decent camera (GoPro Hero) I got curious.
I skype with my friends now and then, but I'm the only one without a webcam...
can I attach my Raspberry Pi to my PC as a webcam?
with as little delay as possible, and a decent FPS (720p30fps is what I'm aiming for)

I know I can just go out and buy a webcam for a few bucks, but why not use my Pi for it for the time beeing.
I prefer USB, but if it's really necessary (because USB won't work for example) I can use ethernet, but that's not ideal

Comment: Skype looks to be [something of a big ask](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=124243) for the Pi, even with an optimal setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have your pi be detected as a USB webcam, you'll need the pi to present itself as a USB device. Depends on which pi device you have, but you can read more here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=35712

Answer (score 0):

Well you mostly have to work on the software side instead of the hardware. I'm sure you're capable of doing this:

- Make the pi act as an IP camera.
- Use [Splitcam](http://splitcamera.com/) on a Windows PC, connect to the Pi, then use the virtual device Splitcam provides on Skype.

Don't expect awesome quality if your network isn't that awesome since it needs to get the (HD preferred) video stream to your PC. You could lower the resolution to get better frame rates and lower delay.